# is POST request with restoring soft delete considered a PUT(update) or POST(store) request?

Tags: laravel, rest

In my laravel code, I can do the following:

```
User::create(['user_id' => 1, 'value' => 1]);
```

which I used **POST** `store` for it, but this field is possibly soft deleted so I use this instead to restore it

```
User::withTrashed()->updateOrCreate(['user_id' => 1], ['value' => 1, 'update_at' => now()])->restore();
```

is this considered a **PUT** `update`?

My understanding is `POST` is when if the user spammed it to give **error** if it is already available after first request, while `PUT` is if spamming will always results in same value in the end, which my code does, too.

Comment: Read the documentation, this is just an example from it: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

Comment: @matiaslauriti i understand it but i wanna know about the proper method for my case

Comment: I would say it is a PUT, because you are updating a state, but still, it is very opinion based and this would not change anything at all, just a line of code of a route definition and a javascript code (or whatever is doing the call) to use `put` instead of `post`

Answer (score -1):

Personally I believe it is up to your use case and how you are already defining your API structure.

- **POST** - would be you creating a new user once, and if you keep calling it either an error would occur with that user already created, or you would create duplicate ones
- **PUT** - is idempotent, which means calling it just once or multiple times will result in the same value
- **[PATCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH)** - is what I would use to update your value back to 1 after it has been soft deleted, this request method applies to partial modification of an object.

In this specific question, if you are saying that you are executing it multiple times and it results in the same result in the end, I would say it would be a PUT/PATCH request method, not a POST